# Finding the current working directory programmatically in go?

Tags: go

I have been looking trough the go documentation but so far I haven't found anything. I need help to find the `current working directory` programmaticly in go language. Does any one know how to do that?

Comment: You should browse the listing of standard library packages and become familiar with what they provide - http://golang.org/pkg/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Getwd](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Getwd) from the os package will return your current working directory. For more operating system related functions look in the `os` package.

If you want to print it do the following.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    wd, _ := os.Getwd()
    fmt.Println("Working Directory:", wd)
}
```

Comment: Honestly I din't even know about the os package. I just started trying out go.

Comment: Notice that the example code above doesn't check the errors. But remember to do so in real programs.